# Alter entity to generate ids for legacy table

Tags: jpa

I have a legacy (old) table with data in a database. Currently, data is put along with ids, so ids are not generated. I'm going to change a source of data. Data from a new source have other ids. These could clash with ids from the legacy table. So I don't want to use them. I'm going to map this data without ids and generate ids with jpa. Will it work if I change my entity for auto-generation and the id column to auto increment? Which options do I have otherwise?

Comment: Yes this works. What other options are you thinking of?

Comment: I meant if it doesn't work. How could I overcome the problem?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli So I need only 1) alter an id in the table and 2) add an annotation to an id in my entity. Right? How should and can I alter the id in my MsSQL DB? What strategy should I choose to generate the next value for the entity id?

Comment: Simply create a column with autoincrement